# Node/Javascript loop synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have followed multiple posts and guides about using async / await, tried multiple synchronous request libraries, I have tried promises, then blocks, callbacks, using regular loops as opposed to foreach loops, and I have run out of ideas.

This code calls the Zoom API to get a list of cloud recordings that I would like to download. Each user can have 100-200 and they are large files, so there is a limit to how many connections either my end or Zoom's end can handle without getting an understandable "RequestError: socket hang up".

Because of how the Zoom API works you can only get results for one month a t a time. So I am looping over users, then looping over months, then calling the individual URLs for stream download to a file on my workstation.

All I want this code to do is process the recordings for a single user in a single month, and WAIT until they have all downloaded, before moving onto the month and then eventually the next user.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to accomplish that?

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("follow-redirects").http;
const https = require("follow-redirects").https;
var syncrequest = require("sync-request");
const got = require("got");
const stream = require("stream");
const { promisify } = require("util");

(async function getFiles() {
  var token  = "TOKEN_HERE";

  var zoomUserIDs;
  var users = ["EMAILS_HERE","EMAILS_HERE"];

  var dates = [
    [9, 2020],
    [10, 2020],
    [11, 2020],
    [12, 2020],
    [1, 2021],
    [2, 2021],
    [3, 2021],
    [4, 2021],
    [5, 2021],
    [6, 2021]
  ];

  var path_to_save = "";
  var folder_name = "";

  //Loop over list of users
  for (const user of users) {
    console.log(user);
    folder_name = "output/" + user;
    if (!fs.existsSync(folder_name)) {
      fs.mkdir(path.join("", folder_name), err => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(user + " Directory created successfully!");
      });
    }

    //Loop over months
    for (const date of dates) {
      var url =
        "https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/" +
        user +
        "/recordings?from=" +
        date[1] +
        "-" +
        date[0] +
        "-01&to=" +
        date[1] +
        "-" +
        date[0] +
        "-31&page_size=100";

      //Call Zoom API
      const res = await got.get(url, {
        responseType: "json",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer" + token
        }
      });

      //Get individual file url
      var reponse = res.body;
      if (reponse.meetings) {
        for (const meeting of reponse.meetings) {
          for (const recording of meeting.recording_files) {
            if (
              recording.recording_type == "shared_screen_with_speaker_view" ||
              recording.recording_type == "shared_screen" ||
              recording.recording_type == "active_speaker"
            ) {
              var path_to_zoom_recording = recording.download_url + "?access_token=" + token;

              //Dowload file    
              const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);
              path_to_save =
                folder_name +
                "/" +
                meeting.topic.replaceAll("/", "_") +
                "_" +
                meeting.start_time.replaceAll(":", "-") +
                ".mp4";

              if (!fs.existsSync(path_to_save)) {
                (async () => {
                  console.log(
                    meeting.topic + " -- " + meeting.start_time + " -- START"
                  );
                  await pipeline(
                    got.stream(path_to_zoom_recording),
                    fs.createWriteStream(path_to_save)
                  ).then(() =>
                    console.log(
                      meeting.topic + " -- " + meeting.start_time + " -- END"
                    )
                  );
                })();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you get rid of the first and last line of this section you will be most of the way there

```
                (async () => {
                  console.log(
                    meeting.topic + " -- " + meeting.start_time + " -- START"
                  );
                  await pipeline(
                    got.stream(path_to_zoom_recording),
                    fs.createWriteStream(path_to_save)
                  ).then(() =>
                    console.log(
                      meeting.topic + " -- " + meeting.start_time + " -- END"
                    )
                  );
                })();
```

The way you have it, your upper level isn't awaiting the pipeline.

Also you are this issue near the top:

```
  for (const user of users) {
    console.log(user);
    folder_name = "output/" + user;
    if (!fs.existsSync(folder_name)) {
      fs.mkdir(path.join("", folder_name), err => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(user + " Directory created successfully!");
      });
    }
```

the `fs.mkdir` command is also not awaited. You can wrap that in promisify, and then await that too, just like you did below with another function.

It seems weird to mix it async/await with `existsSync`, but it probably won't hurt, since you only have one thing happening at once.  It would be nice to also promisfy `fs.exists`, and then await that.

In newer node.js there is a pre-promisified version of all these methods.  You import them from 'fs/promises' I think.  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promise_example

also, for what it's worth, you only have to promisify a function once.  This shouldn't really be in the loop: `const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);`  But node.js probably doesn't mind doing it every iteration, so that is not the issue you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I am a solid old-school OOP programmer and the new async/await, promises, etc... in JS hurt my brain. Is there a good book or course that could bring me up to speed on these new concepts?